# 3ds Max: How to add Custom Attribute to rootNode in C#

Tags: c#, 3dsmax

I've been banging my head against this particular brick wall for a while and could really use some help!

I can test for the existence of an IICustAttribContainer on the rootNode and create a new one if not found. I can test for the existence of an ICustAttrib within the IICustAttribContainer but I cannot find a way of adding a new ICustAttrib to it. Here's my current method:

```
    public Boolean writeProp()
    {
        log( "writeProp()..." );
        getRootNode();
        IICustAttribContainer ICustAttrCont = rootNode.CustAttribContainer;
        if (ICustAttrCont == null) {
            rootNode.AllocCustAttribContainer();
            ICustAttrCont = rootNode.CustAttribContainer;
        }
        ICustAttrib ICustAttr = getParamBlockByName(ICustAttrCont, "myProp");
        if (ICustAttr == null) {
            // Create the new ICustAttrib here but how do I do it??
            ICustAttrCont.AddNewProp( new ICustAttrib() );
        }

        return true;
    }
```

getRootNode() returns the rootNode. getParamBlockByName() looks for the custom attribute and returns it if found.

I have looked deeply into the 3ds Max documentation and seems that I have to use ClassDesc2 to describe the custom attribute and subclass ICustAttrib in combination with ParamBlockDesc2 to define each parameter.

My problem is that the documentation and examples are all in C++ and I can't find examples of how to do this in C#.

Any help or pointers gratefully received.

|Simon

Comment: I think it's easier to learn c++ than to figure out how to use the 3dsmax c# SDK.

Comment: Thanks for reply: I'm adding functionality to an existing tool written in C# so this isn't an option.

Comment: I can't answer your exact question, but a workaround is to execute it in maxscript from the c# code.